# The second volume of "Modern Methods in the Calculus of Variations"

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations

I have recently come across the book [Modern Methods in the Calculus of Variations: $L^p$ Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-69006-3) by Irene Fonseca and Giovanni Leoni. From section *"About this book"*,

> This is **the first of two books** on methods and techniques in the calculus of variations. Contemporary arguments are used throughout the text to streamline and present in a unified way classical results, and to provide novel contributions at the forefront of the theory.
>
> This book addresses fundamental questions related to lower semicontinuity and relaxation of functionals within the unconstrained setting, mainly in $L^p$ spaces. It prepares the ground for **the second volume** where the variational treatment of functionals involving fields and their derivatives will be undertaken within the framework of Sobolev spaces.

From section *"Review"*,

> 1. "This book is **the first of two volumes** in the calculus of variations and measure theory. The main objective of this book is to introduce necessary and sufficient conditions for sequential lower semicontinuity of functionals on Lp-spaces. … This book is very nicely written, self-contained and it is an excellent and modern introduction to the calculus of variations." (Jean-Pierre Raymond, Zentrablatt MATH, Vol. 1153, 2009)
> 2. “This is **the first of a two-volume** introduction into direct methods in the calculus of variations. Its main topic is the analysis of necessary and sufficient conditions for lower semicontinuity on Lp-spaces, as well as of relaxation techniques. … The book provides a well-written and self-contained introduction to an active area of research and will be valuable both to graduate students as an introduction and to researchers in the field as a reference work.” (M. Kunzinger, Monatshefte für Mathematik, Vol. 156 (4), April, 2009)

Could you elaborate on which is the second volume?

Comment: If you search, you’ll find that no second volume has ever appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned at the personal [website](http://giovannileoni.weebly.com/publications.html) of the second author that

> I. Fonseca and G. Leoni, Modern Methods in the Calculus of Variations: Sobolev Spaces, **in preparation**, accepted for publication by Springer.